# the cid says : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' python whats wrong

Tags: python

Explain the error " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType' ".I type the code into the editor and it returns the error.I can't find the Nonetype variable.

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights 
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183 
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220 
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days) :
    if days >= 7 :
        return (40 * days) - 50
    if days >= 3 :
        return (40 * days) - 20
    else :
        return 40 * days
def trip_cost(city , days , spending_money):
    sum = (rental_car_cost(days) +plane_ride_cost(city) +hotel_cost(days) + spending_money) 
    return sum 
print trip_cost("Los Angeles " , 5 , 600)
```

Comment: Please indent your code for better readability

Answer (score 3):

Your `plane_ride_cost` function lacks `else` statement.

It validates "Los Angeles", but you're sending input "Los Angeles ", so it's not a match, not a single condition is met, having no value to return it returns `None`. Later you add that `None` to integer, Python can't handle that.

Either fix input value or write a bit of code in your function to trim leading/trailing spaces. Changing input to lower case or title case can also be useful before comparing it to anything in if statements.